# How to count the number of times variables repeats in a javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, loops

How do I get the array-members and the number of times they repeat (recurrences)?

I currently have this script

```
//COUNT VAL
var curr = '';
var previous = '';
var arr = new Array();
var sorted = count.sort();
for(var c=0; c < sorted.length; c++){
if(sorted[c] != ''){
if(sorted[c] != curr){
var repeat = 1;
arr[sorted[c]] = repeat;
curr = sorted[c];
}
else if(sorted[c] == curr){
repeat++;
}
}
}
alert(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

The values of the array "count" are (I used JSON.stringify):

```
[" 2"," 2"," 2","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]
```

What I expect my script to display... (Im expecting it to return an array)

```
[1: 10, 2: 3]
```

(x: y) x is the number, y is the number of times it repeated.

What I get...

```
[null,1,1]
```

Comment: Your expected results look like an object literal, but enclosed in square brackets which makes it look like an array.

Comment: Sorry if its confusing. Im trying to get an array out it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the summary, ignoring null values

```
var collection = [" 2"," 2"," 2","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null];

var summary = collection.reduce(function(a, b) {
    var tmp = parseInt(b)
    if (!isNaN(tmp)) {
        if (!a[tmp]) {
            a[tmp] = 0;
        }
        a[tmp]++;
    }
    return a;
}, {});

console.log(summary);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and for removing the null values!

Answer (score 2):

```
var a = [" 2"," 2"," 2","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null];

var counts = a.reduce( function(obj, cur){
    if( !obj[cur] ) {
        obj[cur] = 0;
    }
    obj[cur]++;
    return obj;
}, {});
```

Result

```
2: 3
1: 10
null: 13
```

Answer (score 1):

Using your code,

Modify your loop like this,

```
for(var c=0; c < sorted.length; c++){
 if(sorted[c] != ''){
    if(arr[sorted[c]] ){
        var count = arr[sorted[c]];
        count++;
        arr[sorted[c]] = count;
    }
    else{
        arr[sorted[c]] = 1;
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its best possible solution, but it works and save output in array.

```
var arr = [" 2"," 2"," 2","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null];

var obj = {};
var final = [];
var count = 0;
for(var i=0,len=arr.length;i<len;i++){
  if(arr[i] in obj){
     final[obj[arr[i]]] ++;
  }
  else{ 
     obj[arr[i]] = count;
     final[count] = 1;
     count++;
  } 
}

console.log(final);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var repeated = function repeated(arr){
                var res = {};
                for(index in arr){
                    var x = arr[index];
                    if(!res.hasOwnProperty(x))
                        res[x] = 0;    
                    res[x]++;
                }
                return res;
            }
```